# Windows 11 controlling two finger scroll speed on a T490 ThinkPad

Tags: windows-11, touchpad, thinkpad, scrolling

I have a Windows 11 machine (T490 ThinkPad). When I two finger scroll its a bit slower than I'd like. On my Mac there is an option in accessibility settings to change the speed of two finger scroll.

I tried changing the registry values for friction and inertia and that makes it better when I flick, but I'd like the 2 fingers down scroll to be more sensitive. Is there a way to change that setting in Windows or in the driver? I believe it’s a Synaptics touch pad.

On my old T460 the Synaptics driver had an option for it, but the driver settings for this computer only have a settings for "palm check" and not much else.

Comment: Look in Settings for Elan Mouse Driver.   Update the driver, go through Elan settings to see if offered.

Comment: Hmmm I searched the settings for Elan Mouse Driver and I don't see anything under that name?

Comment: In that case what you are looking for may not be available.  That was the only suggestion I had.  I use the Track Point not the Pad.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Google:

1. <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `regedit` → OK (or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Click *Yes* to close the confirmation box
3. Navigate to `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop`
4. Double click `WheelScrollLines` to open it